# Add element to a list which is part of a type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to add a new element of type Transaction as defined:

```
--Build type Transaction--
data Transaction = Transaction {
     start_state :: Int, 
     symbol :: Char, 
     end_state :: Int
} deriving Show
```

to the list of transactions which is part of the following type:

```
--Build type Automaton--
data Automaton = Automaton {
     initial_state :: Int, 
     states :: Set.Set Int,
     transactions :: [Transaction],
     final_states :: Set.Set Int
} deriving Show
```

I have tried to implement the following function:

```
--Add to the automaton a transaction 
insert_transaction :: Transaction -> Automaton -> Automaton
insert_transaction t a = a{transactions =  t : transactions }
```

but it returns the following error:

```
automaton.hs:25:48: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Transaction]’
                  with actual type ‘Automaton -> [Transaction]’
    • Probable cause: ‘transactions’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘transactions’
      In the ‘transactions’ field of a record
      In the expression: a {transactions = t : transactions}
   |
25 | insert_transaction t a = a{transactions =  t : transactions }
   |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I implement this? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transactions` is not really a value of type `[Transaction]`, it's by itself<sup>†</sup> only a record field accessor *to a field* of type `[Transaction]`. I.e., it's a function. GHCi could have told you:

```
Main*> :t transactions
transactions :: Automaton -> Transactions
```

So, to access those transactions, you need to be explicit *what automaton from*, by just giving it as an argument:

```
insertTransaction :: Transaction -> Automaton -> Automaton
insertTransaction t a = a{ transactions =  t : transactions a }
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>“By itself” meaning: when you use it in a normal Haskell expression without special record syntax like `a{transactions = ...}`. There, the `transactions` isn't really an independent entity at all.</sub>

---

There are a couple of alternatives you could consider:

- You can “partially pattern match” on the fields of a record you pass as a function argument.

  ```
  insertTransaction t a{transactions = oldTransactions}
          = a{ transactions =  t : oldTransactions }
  ```
- The `RecordWildCards` extension can bring an entire record's fields in scope as overloaded variables, somewhat like as if you're in an OO method of the class containing those fields. This allows you to write essentially what you had originally:

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
  insertTransaction t a{..} = a{ transactions =  t : transactions }
  ```

  I would **not** recommend this: `RecordWildCards` is an unidiomatic hack around the limitations of Haskell98' record types.
- [Lenses](http://lens.github.io/) are the modern and consequent way to use records in Haskell. You can get them most easily by slightly changing your data definition:

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
  import Control.Lens
  data Automaton = Automaton {
     _initialState :: Int
   , _states :: Set.Set Int
   , _transactions :: [Transaction]
   , _finalStates :: Set.Set Int
   } deriving (Show)
  makeLenses ''Automaton  -- Generates `transactions` etc. not as plain accessor
                          -- functions, but as “optics” which can both get
                          -- and set field values.

  insertTransaction :: Transaction -> Automaton -> Automaton
  insertTransaction t = transactions %~ (t:)
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Another question if you have time. Now I can add my transaction to the automaton by doing `a1 = insert_transaction tr a` nevertheless when I try to print a (by simply typing a on the terminal) the program freezes and does not show it. Do you know why does this happen?

Comment: That seems to be an unrelated question you should ask in a separate thread. (Be sure to include a [MCVE]!)